"Some" depicted
What is the answer to this puzzle?


... and btw, there's only one that works, check the tag ;)

The answer is

 IRELAND! 


 Firstly the rows on the bottom and right need to be interpreted as representing the primary colors  because they hint at the half of the flags highlighted by the position of name of that country, the flags corresponding to the country which is stated:
 Vatican City
 
 Monaco
 
 San Marino
 

Then

 Following the hint from the title, ‘SOME’ which is a homophone for ‘SUM’ the colors are to be mixed together to form the grid shown like so below. Note that the yellows ‘cancel each other’ because of the negative sign on the bottom of the ‘Vatican City’ square on the bottom row. The final result resembles the IRISH FLAG!!
 


This is correct :) The other one would be the flag of I C, but I used the word-tag so that one can be ruled out. Well done!

Also the title hints at rot13("FHZ")

yes I got that dont worry I accidentally edited it out

Nvm my comment regarding I C not even the same orientation, I thought they were identical orientation-wise (silly mistake, didn't double check)
